# Does filtering on top of Hive view push the filter inside the view?

Tags: hive

Let there be a view MyView on Table MyTable as:-

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT col1,col2,...,colN from MyTable;
```

Now lets say we fire the following query:-

```
SELECT * FROM MyView WHERE col="abc";
```

So does Hive push the filter (col="abc") inside the view for the execution of the select? Basically trying to understand if Hive will do 'push down optimization' here, if I can use that term. Because otherwise it will be very inefficient, as the View is on the entire table and after querying the entire table , outside the view the filter will be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES.

```
create view tmp.v_tmp0823 as select city_id, city_name from dw.dim_city ;

explain select city_id, city_name from tmp.v_tmp0823 where city_id = 123 ;

STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: dim_city
          Statistics: Num rows: 530 Data size: 57323 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
          Filter Operator
            predicate: (city_id = 123) (type: boolean)
             Statistics: Num rows: 265 Data size: 28661 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
             Select Operator
               expressions: 123 (type: bigint), city_name (type: string)
               outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1
               Statistics: Num rows: 265 Data size: 28661 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
               ListSink
```